# How to store a random number into a null-terminated character array?

Tags: c, arrays, random, character, null-terminated

I figure using `fgets` is the best option, but apparently it takes input from stdin? How do I generate a random number using `rand()`, and store it?

Comment: Store it how? The most obvious way would be to store it as in decimal notation; if that's what you meant, please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf()`:

```
char buf[11];
int r = rand();
sprintf(buf, "%d", r);
```

A more robust option is to use `snprintf()` if your runtime library offers it:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", r);
```

Using `snprintf()` in this way ensures that the resulting string will not overflow the bounds of `buf`.

Comment: Wouldn't that only store integers up to 10 numbers long? What if it's longer?

Comment: @user1787038: You are correct. In order to store all possible values, you should check to see what the value of `RAND_MAX` is for your platform, and use an appropriate string width. The use of `snprintf()` will avoid overwriting memory past the end of the buffer if your assumptions about maximum size are not met.

Comment: That's a good point, I just changed the declaration to `char buf[11]` to accommodate the NUL terminator for a 10-digit number.

Comment: Buf size should be equal to the number of digit of your RAND_MAX (depends on your computer) + 1 for NUL terminator.

Comment: It is being printed as an int so you'll need to allow for the minus sign as well.

Comment: @Dipstick: Not in this case; the [definition of `rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) states that it returns a nonnegative integer.